What is the point of shared buffers in postgres?
Linux has a built in mechanism that caches filesystem pages in memory, so my understanding was that we can rely on that instead of implementing some separate database cache.
So, my question is, why do we need this shared_buffers setting? What kind of cache does it control? What is stored in that cache? Why do we need it, if the filesystem can cache pages automatically?

PostgreSQL is a system that depends on both shared_buffers as well as system cache. Shared buffers or buffer pool is just like the name indicates, it's a shared area for all sessions connected to Postgres which query or write database containing table/index pages, visibility map etc . Just like system cache database cache also part of system memory but it is exclusively dedicated for database. While system cache may hold data needed for Postgres, it's a global cache shared by all programs running on the system.
Now think of a system where the database installed have some other programs demanding high memory. There is no guarantee that the Postgres will have good cache hit rate. By specifying shared buffer size we reserving a portion of memory just for Postgres itself. Generally 25% of system memory reserved for shared buffers but it's not a golden rule. At the same time a value above 40% is not recommended as it increase chance of duplicate caching both in shared buffers as well as in system cache.
Even though system cache may contain data requested by other programs, for a dedicated PostgreSQL system we expect an average of 75% total cache size including shared buffers as well as system cache , so its often recommended to set effective_cache_size to 75% of system memory. However this parameter does not reserve memory rather it's an estimate of shared buffers+ postgresql data present in system cache.

First of all, PostgreSQL does not only run on Linux, and not all supported operating systems might manage memory in the same way.
Second, even if data are in the kernel page cache, PostgreSQL needs a system call to read these data. That is a small overhead, but still an overhead compared to accessing memory mapped into the database process.

For PostgreSQL's transaction system to work properly, it needs to gaurantee that the WAL records which correspond to an ordinary page in shared_buffers getting dirtied are flushed to disk before the dirty shared_buffers page itself can get written to the kernel (and so possibly written to disk). Violation of that ordering rule could result in crash recovery failing to work correctly. shared_buffers implements this interlock. It is basically a cooling pond where dirty pages can wait a while for their corresponding WAL to get flushed so the data pages can be safely written themselves.
It also serves as way to lock pages so that multiple processes can only access the same page in a safe manner, so that concurrent writers can't stomp on each others writes or the readers can't read partially written changes.  There may be other ways to do this, but PostgreSQL does not just run on Linux and not just on modern Linux, so these ways would need to be both portable and old.  And due to the preceding issue, it would also not be enough.

First, OS filesystems don't usually implement database features like transactions.  For example postgres will write the WAL first, sequentially for high throughput, then it will write modified data (actual tables and indices) when it can. So data that is constantly updated results in a steady stream of WAL and an occasional update of the corresponding pages, which significantly reduces the write load. The order of these writes is crucial as it is what ACID depends upon. To do all this efficiently, it helps if a database can manage how its own data is accessed.
Second, Postgres (or any other process) reading data from its own memory will take from a fraction of a nanosecond if it's in the CPU cache, to tens of nanoseconds if it has to be fetched from RAM.
Relying on the OS to do all the caching would mean having to do a "read block from file" syscall, or the mmap equivalent, every time a page needs to be hit. This means a context switch to the OS and then back, which takes on the order of 1µs. Then of course the OS has to do the work to get the data from its own cache and hand it to postgres. Thus, performance wise, it is generally a bad idea to do a context switch to the OS to read a tiny bit of data: might as well instead request bigger chunks and amortize the cost.
Modern CPUs rely heavily on caching, which means they're very fast at doing not too complicated stuff (so the code fits in the instruction cache) with not too much data (so the data fits in the data cache). Any trip into the OS will necessarily encounter new code and data which the core will load into its caches, evicting much of the stuff that will be needed when it context switches back to the application. This means the cost of a context switch is not just the time it takes, but also the time wasted after it's done to re-fetch what was evicted from cache. Excessive context switching can hit performance really hard.
As a user, the fundamental differences between shared_buffers and the OS cache are:

OS cache is shared between all applications running on the machine, whereas shared_buffers is reserved for postgres only. So if shared_buffers is set too large, it will starve other apps.

shared_buffers is much faster, so ideally you'd want it large enough to accomodate your most often accessed data.


